# ActiveMQ Message Grouping Unit Test

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a requirement to unit test JMSXGroupID in my application. Can anyone advise if there are sample articles or references to achieve this. I tried to see the reference in ActiveMQ portal but looks like the below Hudson link is broken. I am using Spring JMS for programming.

http://activemq.apache.org/junit-reports.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see some tests that exercise the Message groups here:
https://github.com/apache/activemq/tree/trunk/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/usecases

For instance this one shows distribution of messages over a set.
https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/trunk/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/usecases/MessageGroupReconnectDistributionTest.java

For articles you can search Google.